# Does every file have a MIME type associated with it?

Tags: php, security, mime, file-extension

I recently implemented a security system where we check MIME types and file extensions against a list of acceptable ones. If the scanned file has a MIME and an extension in this list, we move forward. I have included the function where we scan the file below. The `ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS` and `ALLOWED_MIME_TYPES` are just strings such as "txt,pdf,jpeg....".

I will assume you know what and how MIME types work, but lately we have been getting PDF uploads with no MIME type at all. This code works most of the time by the way. I have seen PDFs go through fine, as well as images, text files, ect.

Is it possible a file would not have a MIME type at all?

```
 /**
 * scan the file before upload to do our various security checks
 *
 * @param  tmpName    the file's location in /tmp, used for MIME type scan
 * @param  name       the filename as it was uploaded, used for extension scan
 * @param  oid        the order id, passed along to notifyStaffIllegalFileUpload() if email needs to be sent
 * @return            true on success, error string on failure
 */
function scanFile($tmpName, $name, $oid) {
    global $_email;

    // get lists from config
    $allowedExtensions = explode(",", ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS);
    $allowedMIMEs = explode(",", ALLOWED_MIME_TYPES);

    // get extension
    $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // get MIME type
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $tmpName);
    finfo_close($finfo);

    // check against allowed
    if (!in_array(strtolower($ext), $allowedExtensions) || !in_array(strtolower($mime), $allowedMIMEs)) {
        capDebug(__FILE__, __LINE__, "Order #" . $oid . " - A user attempted to upload a file with extension '" . $ext . "' and MIME type '" . $mime . "'. The attempt was blocked.\n", "/tmp/file_errors.log");
        $_email->notifyStaffIllegalFileUpload($oid, $name, $ext, $mime);
        return "Our security systems detected an illegal file type/mime type. The file upload was cancelled.";
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: content-type is a hint to the receiving end as to what's being sent. nothing says that hint HAS to be provided, or be accurate. and on some systems *cough* windows, a file's type is purely determined by its file extension. if you upload an extension-less file, no content-type can proerly get set, except maybe the generic types, like application/octet-stream.

Comment: This, along with some other advice I received from colleagues lead me to the answer. It is not feasible to use MIME types for security checks. Period.

Comment: they're not a security check, period. but they do tell you that the file's outer layer is what it claims to be. but just saying "this is really a pdf" isn't enough. a pdf is essentially a postscript program, and can contain other "active" stuff as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of research and advice, the answer to the question is kind of irrelevant due to the fact that checking for MIME types as a security feature is not feasible in the first place. There are too many issues with MIME types on different operating systems, different applications saving files differently, some files not having a MIME at all, and lastly, the fact that the extension and MIME could be altered by a malicious user or program. Closing.

Comment: You didn't actually close the question, and so it is still in the queue of questions requiring an answer.  If you don't want to accept one of the anwers here, perhaps you really do want to delete your question?  There is a "delete" link next to the [edit] link just below the actual question when you are logged in as the author.  I'm thinking it's kind of vaguely useful, though; maybe accept and keep.

Comment: Yeah your right I need to close it. I'm trying to figure out how now.

Answer (score 1):

The OP's own answer (which doesn't attempt to answer the actual question) aside, this isn't really well-defined.  The content type `application/octet-stream` is generic, and so can be assigned to every file.  On the other hand, it is obviously possible to create files which have no *useful*  content type; how would you label the output of `dd if=/dev/urandom` in terms of a MIME type?

In the frame of the question here I'm leaning towards "no" -- it is not possible to assign a useful MIME type to every possible file.